# How to convert war file to ear package using maven project

Tags: maven, war, ear

I am new bee to maven, i want to convert war file to ear file using maven project.
Can anyone help me.

Comment: lol, I would just rename `.war` to `.ear` ..:) [This](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/real_app.htm#MAVEN8920) might help you..

Comment: Create an EAR project define the WAR as dependency and put it into the modules area of the EAR plugin configuration and build the EAR file?